# Accessing Union inside structure with pointer

Tags: c, struct, runtime, structure, unions

I have the 2 structures definition below:

```
/* Ieee1609Dot2Data */
typedef struct Ieee1609Dot2Data {
    Uint8_t  protocolVersion;
    struct Ieee1609Dot2Content  *content;
    
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} Ieee1609Dot2Data_t;

/* Ieee1609Dot2Content */
typedef struct Ieee1609Dot2Content {
    Ieee1609Dot2Content_PR present;

    union Ieee1609Dot2Content_u {
        Opaque_t     unsecuredData;
        struct SignedData   *signedData;
        EncryptedData_t  encryptedData;
        Opaque_t     signedCertificateRequest;
    } choice;
    
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} Ieee1609Dot2Content_t;
```

I want to Initialize the structure Ieee1609Dot2Data with a pointer to structure.
my main function :

```
int main(int ac, char **av) {

EtsiTs103097Data_t *EtsiTs103097Data; /* Type to encode */

asn_enc_rval_t ec; /* Encoder return value */

/* Encoding Buffer */
uint8_t buffer[128] ={0};

/* Allocate the EtsiTs103097Data */
EtsiTs103097Data = calloc(1, sizeof(EtsiTs103097Data_t)); /* not malloc! */

if(!EtsiTs103097Data) {
    printf("Calloc Failed!");
    exit(1);
}

uint8_t Msg_to_encode[] = "hello" ;

/* Initialize the EtsiTs103097Data memsbers */
EtsiTs103097Data->protocolVersion = 3;
EtsiTs103097Data->content->choice.unsecuredData.buf=(uint8_t*)Msg_to_encode; /* Runtime error */
...

}
```

there is a runtime error (Cannot access memory at address 0x8) at the line when I access choic union.
How can I access the union correctly?

Comment: In the future, always provide a [mre] when asking for debugging assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`EtsiTs103097Data->content` is never assigned a value.

Comment: Please add some more context, this answer landed in the low quality review queue.

Comment: @Superlokkus: Do not completely trust automated processes for judging content. The fact that `EtsiTs103097Data->content` is never assigned a value is the entire cause of the problem OP reports. It is a trivial error not worthy of further discussion.

Comment: I know it is, but you still could elaborate for the OP why that is a problem in his case, like mentioning that unassigned values  are not defined, using them is UB i.e. deref of uninitialized ptrs is UB, what he experienced was UB, that he allocated the struct but nothing for the pointer inside that struct and so on.

Comment: @Superlokkus: Using an uninitialized object with allocated storage duration does not have undefined behavior. It produces an unspecified value, which is different. But that is explained in numerous other questions and answers; going into it here just clutters Stack Overflow. This is a low-value question that should be deleted, as I have already voted to do.

Comment: I can relate to that, but Stackoverflow doesn't have a process for "Here is an half answer, be happy I not just down right down voted your question". Personally I prefer the close question approach too. Also deref of a unintialized ptr is very UB, and that is what he does with `EtsiTs103097Data->content->`